# EF Code First creates a reference table instead of a federated table in SQL Azure Federation

Tags: ef-code-first, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to connect to SQL Azure Federation using Entity Framework code first approach. When I attempt to write to a federated table, EF throws an error saying "There is already an object named [pluralized table name] in the database"

I get this error because I created the federated tables before running the application code. If I delete the tables, then EF will create them for me without throwing an exception, but this time they won't be federated. They will be reference tables instead.

How do I solve this problem? Could I prevent EF code first from attempting to create a table?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer myself.

```
class CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TContext> : IDatabaseInitializer<TContext> where TContext : DbContext
{
   public void InitializeDatabase(TContext context)
   {
   }
}
```

And I call it in my DBContext class like so:

```
static EVENTContext()
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<EVENTContext>());
}
```